# Python BeautifulSoup with "lxml" parser breaks long strings into characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, decode

I noticed a bizarre inconsistency between how Python [3.6.5] BeautifulSoup [4.6.0] with "lxml" [4.2.1] parser handles long `bytes` objects vs long strings. (Apparently, "long" is >16,384=2**14 characters or bytes.)

For example, I download the text of Othello from the MIT website and feed it to BS both in the raw (bytes) form and after decoding to a string. Both objects have the same length, because there are no multibyte characters in the document.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib

url = "http://shakespeare.mit.edu/othello/full.html"
html_raw = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
html_str = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("iso-8859-1")

type(html_raw), len(html_raw)
#(<class 'bytes'>, 304769)
type(html_str), len(html_str)
#(<class 'str'>, 304769)
```

The resulting soup is the same for shorter strings/bytes but differs for longer strings/bytes. Namely, the soup produced from a string abruptly starts treating words as separate characters, while the soup produced from bytes correctly handles the whole file:

```
BeautifulSoup(html_raw[:16410], "lxml")
#... <i>Enter OTHELLO, IAGO, and Attendants with torches</i>
#</blockquote>
#<a></a></body></html>
BeautifulSoup(html_str[:16410], "lxml")
#... <i>Enter OTHELLO, IAGO, and Attendants with torch   e   s   /   i   &gt;   
#   /   b   l   o   c   k   q   u   o   t   e   &gt;      
#
#   A   </i></blockquote></body></html>
```

This holds both for the subset of the document (above) and for the whole document:

```
BeautifulSoup(html_raw, "lxml")
#...
#<p><i>Exeunt</i></p>
#</blockquote></body>
#</html>

BeautifulSoup(html_str, "lxml")
#...
#   p   &gt;   i   &gt;   E   x   e   u   n   t   /   i   &gt;   /   p   &gt;   
#   /   h   t   m   l   &gt;   
#   
#   
#   </i></blockquote></body></html>
```

There is no difference between the outputs when I use "html.parser".

Is this a bug in the implementation of BS? Or am I violating some undocumented (or documented?) assumptions?

Comment: This is pretty sure a bug. Report it to BS.

Answer (score 0):

Not because file size, The problem maybe only happen in Linux because in Windows it work fine. it is because the html has character set of `windows-1252`, adding `.encode()` will solve the problem

```
soup_raw = BeautifulSoup(html_raw, "lxml").encode("iso-8859-1")

soup_str = BeautifulSoup(html_str.encode("iso-8859-1"), "lxml")
```